# Is there a way to display p-values in scientific notation using shiny renderdatatable?

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I am trying to display a data table in shiny using the function renderDataTable. One column of the data is p values. Is there a way to display the p-values in scientific notation? 
I tried functions like sprintf. However, this kind of formatting functions output characters, which makes the sorting function of renderdatatable unusable.

Comment: You can use the `rowCallback` option and the Javascript function `toExponential`.

Answer (score 0):

In R, there is a function called `format.pval` which is intended for formatting p-values.

Usage :

```
format.pval(pv, digits = max(1, getOption("digits") - 2),
        eps = .Machine$double.eps, na.form = "NA", ...)

Arguments

pv      : a numeric vector.
digits  : how many significant digits are to be used.
eps     : a numerical tolerance: see ‘Details’.
na.form : character representation of NAs.
...     : further arguments to be passed to format such as nsmall.
```

Comment: But it still outputs char not numeric

Comment: you can use `as.numeric()` function for conversion